# Dividing by zero in C

Tags: c, operands

When I compile the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x, y = 0;

    x = 1 / y;
    printf("x = %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

It gives "Floating point exception (core dumped)"

However, when I compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double x, y = 0;

    x = 1 / y;
    printf("x = %f\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

It prints "x = inf"

Why does it return x as an infinite value if you're using double but returns an error if you're using int?

Comment: Integers have no `inf` or `NaN`.

Comment: The integer division raises a processor exception, whereas the flaoting point division has a representation.

Comment: A related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23878400/how-processor-handles-case-of-division-by-zero

Comment: @WeatherVane - very nice new icon/avitar...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin you look pretty good yourself!

Comment: The principal reason is that the `1 / 0` => `Inf` is mathematically incorrect, but the floating point numbers are inexact values and it might be that in your calculations the divisor was sooo small that it got rounded to 0, so it is still preferable to produce some result than just crash the entire program so that you'd know where it went wrong. And that's what IEEE 754 does in most cases.

It is not, however, a sensible thing to do with integers, and integers cannot represent infinity.

Comment: Notice that you can get infinity already with `1 / 1e-309`, which is a several orders of magnitude smaller than the mathematical infinity ;-)

Answer (score 8):

The C standard explicitly states that dividing by zero has undefined behavior for either integer or floating-point operands.

C11 6.5.5 paragraph 5:

> The result of the `/` operator is the quotient from the division of the
>   first operand by the second; the result of the `%` operator is the
>   remainder. In both operations, if the value of the second operand is
>   zero, the behavior is undefined.

Undefined behavior means that the standard says nothing about what happens. It could yield a meaningful or meaningless result, it could crash, or it could, as the standard joke goes, make demons fly out of your nose. (Of course the latter isn't going to happen, but it wouldn't violate the C standard if it did.)

Floating-point types, unlike integer types, often have special values that don't represent numbers. The IEEE floating-point standard specifies that division by zero can yield a result of Infinity, which is what your implementation is doing. There is no "Infinity" value for integers. (Note that C implementations may or may not conform to the IEEE floating-point standard.)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14682005/827263) discusses the semantics of division by zero in IEEE floating-point.

Answer (score 4):

C standard defines that the behaviour of a division by zero on operands of arithmetic types is undefined (cf., for example, [this](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.5p5) online C standard draft):

> **6.5.5 Multiplicative operators**
>
> 2 Each of the operands shall have arithmetic type. The operands of the
>   % operator shall have integer type.
>
> 5 The result of the / operator is the quotient from the division of
>   the first operand by the second; the result of the % operator is the
>   remainder. In both operations, if the value of the second operand is
>   zero, the behavior is undefined.

And this rule explicitly includes floating point values, since the term [arithmetic types](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p18) means integral values *and* floating point values:

> **6.2.5 Types**
>
> 18 Integer and floating types are collectively called arithmetic
>   types.

Hence, both of your examples are actually undefined behaviour, and each compiler may specify on its own how to treat your statements. And thus it is standard-conform if a compiler treats the integral-division-by-zero as an exception, whereas the floating-point-division-by-zero gives the special value `inf`. Note: the standard does not define that this has to be the case.

Answer (score 3):

A floating point variable can actually store a value representing infinity. (It is the value `INFINITY` defined in math.h.) But there is no integer representation of infinity, so the only thing to do is fail.

Comment: It's not the only thing to do. There might happen endless things, like [demons may spawn out of your nose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that infinity is not the mathematically correct result of dividing a number by zero -- rather, the result is mathematically undefined.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: True, but the IEEE floating-point standard does specify Infinity as the result of division by zero (for some settings). A C implementation may or may not conform to IEEE.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Shouldn't 1.0/0.0 be NaN then? The infinity comes into play when you take a limit of 1.0/*x* as *x* tends to 0 from the left (- ∞)  or the right (+ ∞).

Comment: @jxh: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14682005/827263 discusses the IEEE rules for division by zero.

Comment: Not in a newbie processor, which would take an inifinite amount of time computing it by subtraction.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: There is no one definition of arithmetic. Arithmetic arises out of axioms, and different systems of arithmetic suit different purposes,

Comment: "so the only thing to do is fail."; actually not - the behaviour is undefined, and one cannot rely that "it fails" (whatever "fail" means).

Comment: @StephanLechner actually IEEE is more applicable here than the C standard.

Comment: @P__J__: Engineering is not a process of guessing which specifications apply. They ought to be stated explicitly, and ideally correct design with desired behavior is logically derived from specifications. This question is tagged C and not IEEE-754, which tells us “This tag should be used with general questions concerning the C language, as defined in the ISO 9899 standard (the latest version, 9899:2018, unless otherwise specified—also tag version-specific requests with c89, c99, C11, etc).” So we are to prefer the C standard as a basis for answering.

Comment: Okay, the result of dividing an integer by zero in C is technically undefined, but it's pretty obvious that on the OP's machine it produces an error. The OP asked why it was generating the error, not if he could rely on that behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil disagreed. All marh hardware and library sofware follows the IEEE not the standard. Si

Comment: @P__J__: No, they do not. Even if they did, the question asks about C, not about hardware or libraries.

Comment: @EricPostpischil this question is not possible to answer without taking into the account the implementation. Then it is UB which form the practical point of view does mean nothing when you do some numeric work

Comment: @P__J__: The notion that the unanswerability of a question justifies making assumptions is absurd. What would be reasonable is stating that C does not define the behavior but observing that the result obtained may be or even likely is because their implementation uses some features of IEEE 754, which is prevalent. Note that using some features of IEEE 754 is not the same as conforming to IEEE 754 and is not assuming that IEEE 754 applies. It is giving information to the OP which can lead them to further learning and investigation without asserting statements not known to be true.