# If I divide 1 by 0 and there is no underlying error handling framework, how is the hardware affected?

Tags: error-handling, binary, hardware

I have implemented error and exception handling while making software without really understanding why we do it. So, hypothetically, if there was no error handling mechanism, I want to know what would happen on the hardware level.

Comment: If there was no error handling mechanism, the processor could generate garbage (the undefined result of a divide by 0), without any action or even notification to the user. This would render the behavior of programs not deterministic.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that software's "error handling framework" detects the division by zero before it reaches the hardware? But in fact, no: the hardware detects the division by zero and generates an "interrupt" for the software's error handling framework to handle. See ["How processor handles case of division by zero"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23878400/978917) for more information; I've voted to close your question as a duplicate of that one.