# How to throw an exception from C while using Android NDK?

Tags: android, exception, android-ndk, abort

I have a random crash in my app deep inside the C++/C NDK layer. Backtraces are not helpful from Google Play Console.

Here is the backtrace:

```
#00 pc 000000000004bba8 /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12) 
#01 pc 000000000001aa13 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+54) 
#02 pc 000000000001f2f9 /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_fatal+24) 
#03 pc 000000000001aedd /system/lib/libc.so (__assert2+16)
```

I am considering to change assert to in my assert wrapper to throw an exception instead.

I saw suggestions from: [How to throw an exception in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891766/how-to-throw-an-exception-in-c) and not sure it's applicable for Android (portability to iOS as well.).

Answer (score 2):

You can throw Java Exception, e.g. `IllegalArgumentException`,  from JNI layer like below:

```
//JNIEnv *env,

jclass jcls = env->FindClass("java/lang/IllegalArgumentException");
env->ThrowNew(jcls, "Argument cannot be null.");
```

Also, you can check Exception status in JNI layer like below:

```
//JNIEnv *env,

jboolean flag = env->ExceptionCheck();
if (flag) {
    env->ExceptionClear();
    /* code to handle exception */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to clarify that you mean throwing a Java exception, for which you want JNI. Specifically the JNI [ThrowException function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp5234).

Any docs you find about throwing exceptions from JNI will apply to Android. (But none of this will work on iOS.)