# Data type for colors in C, i want double/float precision but numbers in range 0-255

Tags: c, graphics, colors, rgb

I have the following code written in C

```
typedef struct{
  unsigned short R,G,B;
}Color;
```

I want to make a data type which would have RGB range for colors but I also want to make it possible for user to enter 1.5 or 55.5 and similar.  So I came up with this but this allows numbers from 0-255 without giving it precision of float/double type numbers. Is there a way that I can make this possible so that a user could type in 0.5 for example but get error from the compiler if it initalizes one of the Color's instances to anything smaller than 0 or bigger than 255?

Comment: What is the *resolution* you want for each color?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, perhaps confused.  Once a user is using a C program the compiler has nothing to do with matters, it has finished its work and gone for a rest.  To implement the behaviour you seem to want you will have to write code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take a value with precision you should declare `R,G,B` as `float` or `double`, not as `unsigned short`.

And i am not sure which type of error you want to get from the compiler. If you want to **print** that, the given value if out of range, you can simply do it like this:

```
if(value < 0 && value > 255){
    printf("Value is out of range\n");
}
```

Or if you want to throw a **runtime error** you may do this like this:

```
if(value < 0 && value > 255){
    value = value/0;
}
```

the `value = value/0` will give a runtime error if the value is out of range.

If you want to learn more about throwing exception in C programing language you can see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891766/how-to-throw-an-exception-in-c) for more information